# How can you make multiple, slideable image galleries from a directory? (Slick Slider)

Tags: php, html, slider, gallery, slick.js

I have made an relative simple html/css/php website for a friend of my. But now he wants to have a page where I can show photos of events in a gallery (Arround 100 photos per event).

I have already searched for some code for this online, what I now have shows all the pictures in that directory but the page gets way to big if there are 100 photos per event.

So now I am wondering if these photos can be put in a slider or something like that.

```
           <?php 

                $dirs = glob('images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
                foreach($dirs as $val) {
                    echo '<div class="gallery">';
                    echo "<a><h3><span>&raquo;</span> ".basename($val). "</h3></a>"; 
                    echo '<ul class="gallery-list">';
                $files = glob($val.'/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
                foreach($files as $file) {
                    echo "<li><a href='".$file."' ><img src='" . $file . "'></a></li> \r\n";
                 }
                    echo "</ul>";
                    echo "</div>";
                } 

            ?>
```

[-- EDIT --]

I managed to combine the code I already had with the slickslider

```
        <?php 
                $dirs = glob('images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
                foreach($dirs as $val) {
                    echo "<div class='gallery-wrapper'";
                    echo "<a><h3>".basename($val). "</h3></a>"; 
                    echo '<div class="slider-photos">';         
                    $files = glob($val.'/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);                        
                foreach($files as $file) {
                    echo "<div class='slide'><a href='".$file."' ><img src='" . $file . "'></a></div> \r\n";    
                       }
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                   } 
       ?>
```

( Ofcourse with the aditional CSS and javascript for the slider, but that is not important for this I think )

But I have one more problem... They automaticaly sort on alphabet but I want them to sort on the date I made the folder where the images are stored. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

And maybe its to much asked, but if it is possible can I also show per folder how many images there ar in that folder?

Comment: Sure, you can. Whats your question here? Just possibility? Then look for one of the thousand jquery sliders. I like the bxSlider

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know there is the possibilty. I already use a Slick Slider on the website but I dont know how I can get the images from my directory in there.

Comment: You also have this part. First you print all images on the side, like your code does. And then apply a Javascript Slider. The Slider will hide all images and only show the current selected. Look at examples here: http://bxslider.com/

Comment: What do you mean with "will hide all images and only show the current selected"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to modify your code a little bit and perform a loop around the div with each slider's content. If you are using slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) then it should be quite straightforward.

1st step is to ensure you have all the required libraries in place:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
// Add the new slick-theme.css if you want the default styling
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

2nd Step is to ensure you initialise your slider:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery-list').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
});
```

});

3rd step is to structure your html correctly using this template:

```
<div class="gallery-list">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

In your case I think this is what you need:

```
<?php 

            $dirs = glob('images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            foreach($dirs as $val) {
                echo '<div class="gallery">';
                echo "<a><h3><span>&raquo;</span> ".basename($val). "</h3></a>"; 
                echo '<div class="gallery-list">';
            $files = glob($val.'/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach($files as $file) {
                echo "<div><a href='".$file."' ><img src='" . $file . "'></a></div> \r\n";
             }
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            } 

        ?>
```